# How to add a post counter to the list of custom taxonomy terms?

Tags: custom-post-types, terms, count

I am using the below code to display the list (radio buttons) of terms that are currently used by existing custom post type posts:

```
$args = array( 
  'taxonomy' => 'typ',
  'post_type' => 'instytucje',
);
$terms = get_terms('typ', $args);
$count = count($terms); $i=0;
if ($count > 0) {
    $cape_list = '';
    foreach ($terms as $term) { 
        $i++;
        $term_list .= '<input type="radio" name="typ" value="' . $term->slug . '"> ' . $term->name . '';
        if ($count != $i) $term_list .= '<br>'; else $term_list .= '<br>';
    }
    echo '<form name="filterby" action="" method="GET">';
    echo $term_list;
    echo '<button OnClick="document.filterby.submit();">Szukaj</button>';
}
```

The list is used as a form to filter posts by terms.

My question is - how can I add a counter showing the number of posts next to each term on the list?

[radio button] [term name] [number of posts with the term]

This is the site I am working on:
http://www.marketingpolityczny.org/baza-wiedzy/instytucje/

Answer (score 0):

Replace the 11th line with the code below (untested):

```
$term_list .= '<input type="radio" name="typ" value="' . $term->slug . '"> ' . $term->name . ' Number of Posts:'. $term->count;
```

It appears that [get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) has a post count return value.